# winsock socket error

Tags: vb6, winsock

followin error in vb6 code:

1) Error(10022) Socket not bound, invalid address or listen is not invoked prior to accept

2) Error 10048 - Address in Use

Comment: No one will be able to help you with the minimal information you've provided. It's also a good idea to check spelling.

Answer (score 1):

- Error #1 occurs when you haven't bound your TCP control to a port, but called .Listen method
- Error #2 occurs when you attempted to listen on a port that is already being listened to by another program or process.